# Repeat a function based on output (SparkAR)

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

**Generate random number (A) -> is A = B? -> if YES ... generate a new A**

I'm trying to recreate this flow but with no luck.
The problem is that Spark doesn't seem to read the variables I'm passing through ([SparkAR - Script to Patch Bridging](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/docs/visual-programming/javascript-to-patch-bridging))

How can I get Spark to pass the right value? For reference this is my logic flow. What's not working is the "if/else" part.

```
 Patches.outputs.getBoolean('correctBool').then(myVar=>{
  });

  function newRandom(){
  if (myVar == true){
    Diagnostics.log('True')
  } else {
    Diagnostics.log('False')
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you need ScriptToPatch bindings? Is it necessary in your scenario?